# creating my first react app and my fontawesome icon is not displaying or loading?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, font-awesome

My font awesome icon is not working. It just popup with a square. I've linked a cdn to on my `index.html` but still its not working. It s my first react app and I was trying to insert a icon for a github. My code is simple boilerplate for react and i have just include icon tag inside a root element. I need a best solution for this problem?

[image]

Comment: for better responses, dont just provide with your issue ,but your code as well .If you are having an issue with functionality , provide images . And add the font in `index.css` and put it inside `body{}` ,be sure to reference it in `index.html`

Comment: How did you install the font? via cdn, package, ...?

Comment: As explained in the comment above, please provide more details such as code snippets, images etc

Comment: You can check your browser network dev tools, maybe fontawesome CSS or fonts files aren't loading. Also, as suggested by others, improve your question, also add the fontawesome version and steps you followed to add it.

Answer (score 0):

## How to use font awesome

---

1) you have to generate `font awesome kit` first by login on [Creating and use this kit](https://fontawesome.com/start)

2) A script tag will be sent to your mail

somewhat similar to this

```
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/12532eg3q2a.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

3) just put it in your `main file` and then you can use `font-awesome-icons` only the one which are free!